# Shutdown Problem on elementary OS Hera

Tags: graphic-drivers, release-hera

I have an intel pentium g4400 cpu with a Nvidia GTX 1060 Grapchic Card. I've installed elemetary OS Hera on it and after installing the graphic card driver I can't shutdown. The PC freezes at elementary logo forever. Please help.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Try hit **Esc** and see what it says/where it stalls, eventually take a picture of it.

regards

Answer (score 0):

If this is a laptop, try from a terminal session

'sudo prime-select intel'

That should disable the nvidia gpu. Try rebooting (it might hang one last time). And then do multiple boot cycles and please report back.

Hitting **ESC** (as previously indicated) might give you some more information of what's going on in the backend.

-Aldo